# Please stop refreshing the Job ads on every page load

Tags: support, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

When I load a page (and then reload that page), I would expect to see the same job ad pop up, even if I just loaded that page.

However, every time I reload a page, I get a new job ad.

This is undesirable for me all the time, but especially in these situations:

1. Visit question. Vote to close question, since I'm a moderator the page auto refreshes to show it's closed. Woe to me if I see an interesting Job ad right before that page refreshes.
2. Visit homepage.  See interesting job ad as I refresh to see new questions.  Job ad gone.

This has been bothering me for a while now, but I figured other people would complain.

Job ads should stick around across page refreshes, especially if it's a fast page refresh.  I shouldn't see the same Job ad for the rest of the day; but it shouldn't be refreshed every second, either.

Comment: This is SE's insidious ploy to keep you from finding a new job so you'll always have plenty of time to mod.

Comment: I don't think this is a bug...more like a feature-request.  Nothing is broken, nor any exceptions thrown, so it's definitely not a bug.  In fact, its [status-by-design].

Comment: There's been a couple times I saw something I would have wanted to read, forgot about this, and lost it when I types in my answer.

Comment: I would like to see this, too, but it's definitely a feature request that is not going to be trivial to implement.

Comment: @Pekka웃 implement caching to bust from each pageload to changing once a few minutes?

Comment: That may have other side-effects, though - like notifications not updating. Not saying it can't be done, just that it probably comes with more unintended consequences than we'd think

Comment: Creating a client side userscript/Chrome extension to save a list of all the job titles and URLs would be my recommendation. Should be pretty easy to scrape those details off the page so you can see the full list anytime.

Comment: Right-click, open in new tab. Do it to all that seem interesting and you're good.

Comment: I imagine that this would have some impact on the billing structure as well. Typically advertisers pay for # of impressions and/or # of clicks. I'm not sure if that is how SO Jobs operates, but if it is then the # of impressions becomes harder to calculate. If you refresh the page and see the same ad, is that 1 impression or 2? Even if it is not impression based, I'm sure there is a certain amount of "air-time" that the advertisers are expecting for whatever it is they pay.

Comment: I completely disagree with this request.

Comment: I completely agree with this request.

Comment: I am completely undecided about this request.

Comment: Err why? I stand on the opposite pole. I would get bored in a few load and add that div into my ad blocker list :/

Comment: Btw, if you really not happy with your se job, ctrl click that ad and you would be happy.. :p

Answer (score 51):

To be fair, that's how just about all web advertising works. When you refresh the page there isn't really any expectation that the same ads will appear.

It's certainly not impossible. We could do it with http caching or Redis caching by user. Though, that makes it sound more trivial than it would be in practice, and there are certainly other implications that we'd have to think through before considering such a system. It's also questionable whether that's really the behavior most users even want. We've generally found that people like variety, in fact we recently started biasing towards showing you jobs that you've seen less frequently, and it results in a significant improvement. So I'm skeptical of the idea.

Honestly, the easiest solution is just... if you see something you want to click on, click on it *before* you refresh. Also, if you remember some of the job details, like company name, location, title, you can always go to the Jobs tab and search for it.

Comment: If you're tracking who's seeing the ads already, might a "jobs you saw advertised today" queue on a user's Jobs homepage make any sense?

Comment: @Josh that would be really cool. I've found myself wishing for that on the sites I frequent the most.

Comment: @JoshCaswell yeah, that might be possible. We don't currently track them in real-time though. We rebuild the list of what you've seen recently once per day, and we keep a 28-day rolling window. And we don't keep it ordered by exactly when you saw them, it's more just you've seen job-x n number of times in the last 28 days. So again, might be possible, but if built off of current infrastructure, it would be somewhat limited.

Comment: I think the reason it surprises me is that I don't think of your Job ads as ads, I think of them as content.  I generally click on them *much* much more than I do ads; and sometimes I just don't notice them until I'm taking an action like closing a question or editing a question that refreshes the page on me.

Comment: The problem with clicking before I go to a different page is that somehow the listings always catch my eye *after* I've clicked.  That "recently seen" list sounds like a good idea.

Comment: @BretCopeland, what if you just tracked it client side?  Job ads setcookies with job IDs that expire after 24 hours, and there's a page that shows the user the jobs based on those cookies?

Comment: @DanField cookies are pretty limited. For example, they wouldn't follow logged-in users across sessions on different computers. We also consider it generally undesirable to add more cookies, or more data in cookies, because that's data that has to be transmitted on every request to our domain, and most of the time it's completely unnecessary. Plus, I think the notion that we're going to be setting more cookies every single time you visit Stack Overflow would sound pretty unappealing to many SO users.

Comment: All good points, maybe in this case a browser plugin really would be best for users who want this.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs please read the earlier comments.

Comment: @BretCopeland It sounds to me like the limitations wouldn't be a problem. People don't want to see the same jobs over and over; they just want the chance to go look at them after one caught their eye and they missed it. I don't think everyone wants to go look at job listings they haven't seen for 2 months. If they do, they can bookmark it when it first catches their eye and come back later. The problem is you only have *one* chance to grab it. Something as simple as a single "last seen" timestamp on the "seen" list and then ordering a list by it would seem to solve the problem.

Comment: You might be interested that YouTube shows you the same random selection of videos when you reload an old page by hitting back on the browser for the exact reason stated by George

Answer (score 6):

I'd think the more useful thing would be a link under the ad taking you to a page showing you the last X ads that were shown to you; perhaps that page could also link to a list of all current campaigns.

This would address the issue raised in your question, and also handle that "Ah, you know, I'm sure I saw an ad on SO yesterday that would address this thing I just ran into..."

Answer (score 5):

Workarounds:

- Right click, open in new tab/window.  I never know if an add will open in a new tab or pull me from the current page, so I always do this (unless it is a flash ad in which case I take the chance since they almost always open in a new tab).  This is great because you can queue up the link as soon as you see it without interrupting your workflow.
- Create a plugin or extension.  There was a thread a few months back on another SE site with a nice extension which would block all Star Wars related questions.  Once installed it was transparent, so your experience was unaffected.  The same could be done here, except track which ads are shown so you can look it up later if you realize you missed one.
- Realize it is an ad.  While the jobs advertised might be relevant to what you do on SO (so a good fit for you), they are the same ads you can get by going to the Jobs site and searching.  The difference is that you probably know better what you are interested in than the site does, so you should be able to get yourself better results.  Saw a job you thought was interesting?  Maybe it is time to check if there are any jobs you would like to apply for.

It does not sound like your request would be easy for the developers to implement.  Hopefully these simple tricks will help you bridge the gap.

Comment: Or just press escape _really fast_!

Comment: Small addition to your first point - if you have a middle mouse button, then clicking that saves an action to open in new tab/window.

Answer (score -1):

I usually don't look at these ads. I prefer RSSes with my specified criteria. For example from search:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=grails&allowsremote=true

you can obtain nice RSS feed:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed?searchTerm=grails&allowsremote=True

Now you won't miss any interesting for you offer.

Comment: That's not bad advice (didn't know you could do this), but it arguably doesn't have anything to do with the situation at hand.